# django-select2: Select Field doesn't open when tabbed

Tags: django, django-select2

In my simple Django App, I've implemented **django-select2**. I have a form with 2 fields: **product** and **category**.  When I create a new product I first give it a title and than tab to the category-field, but the dropdown does not open automatically. Only when I press Space-Bar or Enter the dropdown opens.

What can I do so that the dropdown opens automatically, when it is reached?

Here my code:

```
forms.py
from django import forms
from django_select2.forms import Select2Widget, ModelSelect2Widget, Select2MultipleWidget
from .models import Product, Category


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = ModelSelect2Widget(queryset=Category.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'category']

        widgets = {
            'category': Select2Widget,

        }
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

product.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
{{ form.media.css }}
<br>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form}}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
{{ form.media.js }}
{% endblock content %}
```